# Varnish cached blocks

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, cache, varnish, turpentine

I configured Varnish. And Everything works fine. But some blocks are cached (but they shouldn't). I use [Turpentine](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html) extension.
For example in my layout:

```
     <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
     </reference>
```

In `turpentine_esi.xml` I have:

```
    <reference name="catalog.compare.sidebar">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>private</access>
                <flush_events>
                    <catalog_product_compare_add_product/>
                    <catalog_product_compare_remove_product/>
                    <catalog_product_compare_item_collection_clear/>
                </flush_events>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

But when I add product to compare(via ajax) the compare block's info didn't flush.

Also, if I `restart varnish`, compared product appeared.

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor?

Comment: Not yet, I want to find reason firstly

Comment: Are you using EE FPC (or any other full page caching module) in addition to Turpentine?  Most are not compatible with Turpentine.  Have you, by chance, changed the default compare block in your theme?

Comment: No, I disabled FPC. I will try to modify block

Comment: I was asking if you modified the block because, out of box, Turpentine punches a hole for the product compare block.  If you have, in your custom theme, customized or changed that block, you might see issues.

Comment: I it possible that you redeclared the block in a layout file that is loaded after turpentine_esi? If so then you need to add the action method there because the node is just overridden (had this problem when working with packages).

Comment: Why not change your ajax request to a post. That way varnish won't cache the request.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Turpentine, a third party module made by Nexcess